# Why does my recursive function print in descending order and then in ascending order?

Tags: c++

I have a simple recursive `c++` program and I am trying to understand exactly how it works. I understand why the program prints out `3 2 1`, but then I don't understand why it goes the other way and prints `1 2 3`. I used a hand-simulation and walked through the program step-by-step but still don't understand how the `1 2 3` comes about. I found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/) article from GeeksForGeeks but am still having difficulty grasping the concept. Any explanation would be awesome.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(int n)
{
  if (n > 0)
  {
    cout << n << " ";
    test(n - 1);
    cout << n << " ";
  }
}

int main()
{
  test(3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's caused by the second `cout << n << " ";` line.

Comment: *I used a hand-simulation and walked through the program step-by-step but still don't understand how the 1 2 3 comes about.*  -- If you did do all of that, then maybe an improvement of your walk-through skills (or tell us) where you are getting lost (after you've read the answers given)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm getting lost after the `3 2 1`. How does it then run it from the other way and print `1 2 3`?

Comment: It is not running it the other way, each call to the function has two prints.

Comment: Go through the function by hand carefully.  Or try just 2 numbers instead of 3.  I know that recursion sometimes is tricky, but if you do *exactly* as the program states and do not deviate (you are now a machine, not a human), you should see why you get the output you're seeing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is it adding the numbers to the stack and then printing the most recent one off first?

Comment: Don't guess -- do exactly what the program is stating.  Believe it or not, the program isn't doing anything out-of-the-ordinary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I still can't grasp how it works.

Comment: Honestly, you're thinking too hard.  Again, forget about any preconceived notions of what you think the program should do -- just follow the program flow *exactly* as written.

Comment: @AlexLowe recursivity use a LIFO stack. LIFO means **last in, first out** that means last context in saved, first context out executed. when you print : 3, 2, 1 ? the last context add is context 1 (**test (1);**) so it is the first context out to execute (that why we print 321**1**), befor context 1 we have added context with 2 (**test (2);**) in stack, that why you have 3211**2**, ....

Comment: A different take on it: [Ariadne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariadne)

Answer (score 6):

The order of function calls in your recursion looks something like this:

```
test(3)
-- cout << 3 << " ";
-- test(2)
-- -- cout << 2 << " ";
-- -- test(1)
-- -- -- cout << 1 << " ";
-- -- -- test(0)
-- -- -- cout << 1 << " ";
-- -- cout << 2 << " ";
-- cout << 3 << " ";
```

Comment: Why does the program not just stop after going `3 2 1`?

Comment: @AlexLowe Because you are printing after the recursive call too. Remove the second `cout` if you don't want that.

Comment: @AlexLowe Because the called functions are staying open. It is as if you have 3 seperate functions called that wait until the if command is not valid anymore and the test doesn't call itself. When that happens the second cout gets called and the still open test functions get closed one after another. I wrote an answer on how I represent my data that I understand the algorithm - have fun to read it :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your program to

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(int n)
{
  if (n > 0)
  {
    cout << "enter" << n << " ";  // <- add "enter" here
    test(n - 1);
    cout << "exit" << n << " ";   // <- add "exit" here
  }
}

int main()
{
  test(3);
  return 0;
}
```

and you will see next output

```
enter3 enter2 enter1 exit1 exit2 exit3
```

You can think about recursive calls as operations with a stack.
There are two operations: `push` and `pop`.
What your program does is

```
push test 3
push test 2
push test 1
pop test 1
pop test 2
pop test 3
```

On every `push` and `pop` you do `cout` and thus see the output `3 2 1 1 2 3`.

[Here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/) you can find more about recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that all the answers don't help you because even if someone got it explained to you, you will stuck in the next algorithm.

I am offering a fundamental approach that helped me a lot with understanding some search algorithms, linked lists, binary trees and much more because I am a simple mind.

What you have to do is figuring out ways to represent the data in the most creative ways you can come up with. Because programming is just flipping data in lots of ways. A few examples I came up with is using plastic cans and post its or grapes and plates, I've seen some indian video guys that draw the data flow on charts or just with circles on a sheet of paper with different colors if you want
and that works as follows:

1. put the data on the post its, one for each round. You got a simple algorithm and I would write a "3" because it is passed through the function.
2. The jars, represent the function calls, I would take a jar for every call.
3. Simulate the algorithm bit by bit. Like taping the 3 on the jar -> first cout "3" -> test get called "n - 1" so "2" goes in a new jar (writing 2 on the post it)
   -> second cout "2" -> test get called "n - 1" so 1 goes again in a new jar. (writing 1 on the post it)
   ->third cout "1" -> test get called "n - 1" so 0 goes in a new jar. (writing 0 on the post it) - but wait! 0 is not bigger as 0! So that jar won't pass the if command! so the test doesn't gets called again - function over.
   Now look at your place! you got still 4 jars and the second cout in the function is not even called once - now its time because every jar represents one function call that is not finished and still open. what number is in the jar you put in last? Right, a 1! So "1" get to the cout. Crumple the post it, put the jar back. What is in the next jar? a "2"? bingo - that is printed through the second cout. The last cup has a 3 in it? - right, print it with cout than crumple the post it up. No cups anymore? No data to print out? you done! 
   Thats how the program works!
   Congrats, because I am sure you grasped it now! :)

Btw. if you come to a point where you don't know where the data flows, every good IDE has a debugger that let you run exactly the steps the program does and it stops after every step. It is really good explained how to use a debugger in alex allain "jump to c++" and he has a whole chapter on how to read and write a program, also a whole chapter about recursion and i think 6 for pointers alone. He gave the tip to find ways to represent data and I hope that helps you as much as it helped me :)

Cheers

Comment: I am using an IDE, `Clion` and am able to visually walk through the program but I still don't quite understand it.

Comment: @AlexLowe So how would you represent data? I am sure you can come up with something that fits your brains needs.

Comment: Maybe that helps:
That test function print the first cout and takes kind of a  break 3 times until the if function stops the recursion/calling itself and "rings the bell" that "the break is over". Than the last function gets to finish with the second cout, than the forlast function until the first called function get to turn the cout out.

Maybe sleep a night over it and give yourself time to process it :) (or play the jar game - actually get real jars and postits and play through it - i did it the same)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the cout statement after calling the "test" method in your if-statement. After it walks down all the method calls and hits the base case, it then returns out of each of those method calls moving on to the next line (the cout statement) in the reverse order the methods got called in.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear rewrite the function

```
void test( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        std::cout << n << " ";
        test( n - 1 );
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
}
```

the following way

```
void test( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        std::cout << n << " ";
        std::cout << n << " ";
        test( n - 1 );
    }
}
```

That is move the second statement

```
std::cout << n << " ";
```

above the statement

```
test( n - 1 );
```

For the call `test( 3 );` of the modified function you will get the following output

```
3 3 2 2 1 1
```

So each recursive call of the function two times outputs the passed value n. I hope it is clear because the function explicitly contains the same statement two times

```
std::cout << n << " ";
std::cout << n << " ";
```

Now returning to the original function definition we see that between the two outputs of the same value `n` the function calls itself with the value `n - 1`.

So each function call outputs the same value two times but between the outputs the function calls itself recursively.

Now the output can look like

```
3         3
     |
call itself for 2
```

... and so on.

Comment: I understand when the print statement is above the recursive function, but not below.

Comment: @AlexLowe Consider each recursive call as a separate call with value n and between two outputs the function is doing something.